# Age Verify Javascript in Mobile Site Pop Up Overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I needed a Pop up javascript for Age verification and found one, hosted it in google drive and successfully implemented it after so much of juggling. The script works fine in desktop but in the mobile version (link is below with m. ), the shopping cart button, tracking button etc, overlap the pop up age verify script. I dont know js, html etc but am learning a bit. Can Anyone Help? 
Also, i noticed that the background coulor in the desktop somehow fades once the wepage fully loads- i am assuming once the JS loads or completely runs - the background theme colour goes away. Help would be appreciated.

Desktop Site:
http://electroniccigaretteaus.com.au/

Mobile Site:
http://m.electroniccigaretteaus.com.au/

I doont know much about js and how it works etc, but can do some of the stuffs myself if i get clear instruction. Help would be appreciated- thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an div element with `id = "modal_content"`. Set `CSS` property `z-index` to it as below:

```
#modal_content{
  z-index:10000
}
```

Comment: Are you asking me if there is the code you have mentioned?

Comment: And to be specific  - the overlap problem is with the mobile site: http://m.electroniccigaretteaus.com.au

Comment: No am asking you to add the above code anywhere in any `stylesheet`, and yea I am speaking about `mobile-site` itself..

Comment: width: 100%;
 z-index: 1100;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);

Comment: This above code is already there. So to be clear do i add the code above in the css related to this js. Also why do you think the background colour fades in desktop once page loads completely

Comment: `z-index` was there but value wasn't enough. So I just increased it.. now if this has solved you problem do mark this answer as accepted by click **right** on the left side of answer.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an div element with `class="wCenterIn"` set `css` property `z-index` to it as below:

```
.wCenterIn{
z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: I Added this: #modal_content{
  z-index:10000
}

Comment: fixed the issue with overlap on mobile. But still not sure about why the desktop site backgroud is fading